# Twitter Bootstrap input append breaks on row-fluid

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap together with their responsive flavor.  I'm having some problems with input-append and adding a "%" to the end of an input.  I realized that removing the "-fluid" from "row-fluid" solves the issue.

1. Would it be ok to use a div.row inside of a div.container-fluid?
2. How could this be fixed: http://jsfiddle.net/zhenghao1/svrec/

Thanks in advance everyone!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A quick way to do this is by floating the `input` to the left. Add the following to your style.css and remove the `span2` class from your input (use a % or fixed width instead).

```
.input-append input { float:left; width:10% }
```

Also, be sure to include bootstrap-responsive.css in addition to bootstrap.css to ensure everything sizes correctly based on your viewport.

http://jsfiddle.net/eterpstra/eXVuM/
(By default, the form switches to 'vertical' orientation when the screen size narrows to < 768px. That is why you see your label flipping to the top if the jsFiddle window is too narrow.)

Comment: Thanks this really helped.  Sorry for late reply

Comment: Thanks for the hint with the "span"-classes. Unfortunately I'm trying to get row-fluid, input-appends and different span-widths working at the same time. Maybe another idea/hint to realize this, or even maybe a reference how the Twitter-Bootstrap developers handle this issue?
Thanks and kind regards